Declare type for a function that unfolds a function and that function is called with a Record whose elements can be a function or a string
How to declare the type of funcfi in the code below so that there is no error (indicated in the comments in the anonymous function on the key press event of window.
let nextI = 0

function next<T>(arr: Array<T>): T {
  if (nextI >= arr.length) nextI = 0
  return arr[nextI++]
}

export function funcfi<T, U>(val: T): T extends () => U ? U : T { 
  return typeof val === "function" ? val() : val
}

const keysReplace: Record<string, Function|string> = {
  "[a] -": "—",
  '[a] "': () => next(["«","»"]),
  "[a] '": () => next(["«","»"]),
  "[a] .": "…",
}

window.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
  let key = `${e.ctrlKey ? "[c] " : ""}${e.altKey ? "[a] " : ""}${e.key}` 

  key = funcfi(keysReplace[key]) || key  
  // here the LSP server reports an error:
  // Type 'string | Function' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'string'.

  // ...
  if (key.length === 1) document.body.innerText += key
  // ...
})

the same code, but in the form of a screenshot for clarity. With error message from LSP:


Did you mean (() => T) | T? Currently that's () => (T | T).

No, I didn't actually think about that. Indeed, it would be more correct to write (() => T) | T. Then an error will appear inside the function itself, which indicates that not all components of the type are callable. And unfortunately, this separates me even more from the answer.

()=>T|T seems more like a typo and not like the actual problem, which is the bulk of the answer below and the topic of the linked q/a above.

There's an issue with precedence here. The type ()=>T|T is actually interpreted as () => (T | T) and not as (() => T) | T as you desire. That's easily fixed with some parentheses:
export function funcfi<T>(val: (() => T) | T): T { 
  return typeof val === "function" ? val() : val
}


Next up, you'll notice that this does give a type error, because val might not be callable without arguments even if it's a function. That is because T itself might be a function, which takes different arguments.
I tried to express the constraint "T is not a function" using T extends Exclude<any, Function>, but that's fundamentally the wrong approach: you could no longer pass a function that returns a function.
A better way is to infer the return type instead: if T is a function without parameters, the return type of funcfi<T> is the return type of T, otherwise, the return type of funcfi<T> is T itself:
export function funcfi<T, U>(val: T): T extends () => U ? U : T { 
  return typeof val === "function" ? val() : val
}

This works:
funcfi(42) // Returns 42
funcfi(() => 42) // Returns 42


Caveat: it also calls functions that do take parameters. But that's a problem with the implementation, not with the type declaration.
funcfi((foo: number) => foo) // Returns undefined

If you want to forbid passing functions that have (required) parameters, you can use a helper type like this:
type FunctionOrValue<T> = T extends Function ?
  (T extends () => any ? T : never) :
  T

export function funcfi<T>(val: FunctionOrValue<T>): T {
  return typeof val === "function" ? val() : val
}

This type expands to T, unless T is assignable to Function but not to () => any. In that case it expands to never, forbidding the use of that type.

Thanks for your reply. I didn't know that you can use a unary operator in a type declaration. But this also does not solve the error that appears in the code that is shown on the screenshot in the question.

Please don't post code or errors in screenshots. And please edit your question to provide a minimal reproducible example of a call that still fails with my approach.
